# Set all bits in unsigned to 1 if equal, 0 if not

Tags: c++

How can I achieve the following with the minimum number of Intel instructions and without a branch or conditional move:

```
unsigned compare(unsigned x
  ,unsigned y) {
    return (x == y)? ~0 : 0;
}
```

This is on hot code path and I need to squeeze out the most.

Comment: I guess, `x == y ? ~0 : 0` is quite fast. `(x == y) * ~0` could be faster may be. But you should try this on your platform (or guess by the produced assembly code).

Comment: why `unsigned` instead of `bool` ? I mean to make it more efficient I would start by removing the most obvious redundancy which is storing many 1s/0s when a single one would suffice

Comment: If optimization on "bit level" is an issue, it's worth to mention [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Comment: Why unsigned? Because I need the result of the compare as a bit mask for another operation.

Comment: Note that you probably want to use `~0U : 0U` to ensure that you have the right number of bits - maybe not so worrying for `int`, but if you were to change to a `long` for example, this could be a possible issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC solves this nicely, and it knows the negation trick when compiling with -O2 and up:

```
unsigned compare(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
    return (x == y)? ~0 : 0;
}

unsigned compare2(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
    return -static_cast<unsigned>(x == y);
}

compare(unsigned int, unsigned int):
        xor     eax, eax
        cmp     edi, esi
        sete    al
        neg     eax
        ret
compare2(unsigned int, unsigned int):
        xor     eax, eax
        cmp     edi, esi
        sete    al
        neg     eax
        ret
```

Visual Studio generates the following code:

```
compare2, COMDAT PROC
        xor      eax, eax
        or       r8d, -1                    ; ffffffffH
        cmp      ecx, edx
        cmove    eax, r8d
        ret      0
compare2 ENDP
compare, COMDAT PROC
        xor      eax, eax
        cmp      ecx, edx
        setne    al
        dec      eax
        ret      0
compare ENDP
```

Here it seems the first version avoids the conditional move (note that the order of the funtions was changed).

To view other compiler's solution try pasting the code to
https://gcc.godbolt.org/ (add optimization flags).

Interestingly the first version produces shorter code on icc. Basically you have to measure actual performance with your compiler for each version and choose the best.

Also I would not be so sure a conditional register move is slower than other operations.

I assume you wrote the function just to show us the relevant part of the code, but a function like this would be an ideal candidate for inlining, potentially allowing the compiler to perform much more useful optimizations that involve the code where this is actually used. This may allow the compiler/CPU to parallelize this computation with other code, or merge some operations.

So, assuming this is indeed a function in your code, write it with the inline keyword and put it in a header.

Comment: The function is indeed part of a bigger framework (and it is marked inline). I am wondering if the BMI2 instruction set allows an even shorter version?

Comment: clang 4.0 (which is what I am using) also produces a the cmov version.

Answer (score 3):

`return -int(x==y)` is pretty terse C++. It's of course still up to the compiler to turn that into efficient assembly.

Works because `int(true)==1` and `unsigned (-1)==~0U`.